# Firebase DebugView, how to remove a debug device?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Is there any way to remove debug device from my production Firebase project? When I run my Flutter app in debug mode with dev flavor my device still is visible in the wrong Firebase project (the prod one). I wonder whether I can remove that particular device from my prod project and use it with my dev project. Here my app/build.gradle

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "app"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Dev iVault"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "app"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "iVault"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should disable developer options or revoke usb debugging authorization on the device you wanted to be removed and that should remove it from DebugView.

To Disable Developer Options on Android:

1. Open your android phone’s settings by clicking on the silver gear.
2. Tap ‘Developer Options’ in the settings menu.
3. Tap the slider button at the top right of the screen Off.

To revoke usb debugging authorization:

1. Go to developer options, turn on USB debugging and then turn it off
2. Tap "Revoke USB debugging authorizations", then confirm

[image]